# Adaptive Group Lasso

Tags: lasso, algorithms, software

Is there any code/algorithm (preferrably for MatLab, but R is fine) where I can easily implement the Adapative Group Lasso as in [here](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0167947308002582).

I have found algorithms to implement the [group lasso with a general weight](http://pages.stat.wisc.edu/~myuan/papers/glasso.final.pdf), but not specific (for each group) ones.

Comment: You'll have to roll your own $\sqrt{n}$-consistent initial estimator $\tilde \beta$ for $\beta$, but once you have that, can't you just multiply the design matrix in each group (possibly after orthonormalizing) by $\lVert \tilde \beta \rVert_2^{-\gamma}$ and then apply an algorithm for the group lasso with a general weight?

Comment: Yes, that seems to do the job. I will give it a try. Thanks.

Comment: If that works well for you, consider answering your own question so that others (or just as likely, your future self) can benefit from your research.